# define field which has data type varbinary in loopback data model

Tags: sql-server, typescript, loopbackjs

I have a field called Content where the content from uploaded file will be saved which has data type varbinary(max)
 i.e 
Content varbinary NULL -----> from sql server.

I want to write a data model in loopback which data type Should I use? 
After searching on internet I feel I can use Node.js Buffer object but dont know how to use it for this field. 
Can someone please tell me?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you are looking for a tutorial.

Comment: I tried with buffer data type. It would be helpful if I get some article or tutorial for this one. I am working on one project where there is a logic I have to write for file uploading. For that I have table and want to create data model